# Get all registered generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

In our ASP.NET Core project, we registered generic classes in DI for cache management. In that way, we can partition the cache in logical part following the generic parameter that we inject.

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMemoryCacheManager<>), typeof(MemoryCacheManager<>));
```

And we inject it like this :

```
IMemoryCacheManager<Class1> cache
IMemoryCacheManager<Class2> cache
```

But sometimes I need to get all instances of IMemoryCacheManager in one time, to clear the cache (for exemple). Can I achieve this with DI ?

EDIT 1
This code compile :

```
var services =_serviceProvider.GetServices(typeof(IMemoryCacheManager<>));

foreach (ICacheManager item in services)
    item.Clear();
```

But I have this exception : The number of generic arguments Provided is not equal to the arity of the generic definition types

Comment: Usually you resolve all registered types with `IEnumerable<T>`, where T is your registered type. Dunno on top of my head if that works for open generics though

Comment: It's looks like it's impossible, see this issue : https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/444

Comment: Technically you could also register your types as `services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMemoryCacheManager<object>), typeof(MemoryCacheManager<Class1>));` (dunno if the untyped version already does that) and resolve it via injecting `IEnumerable<IMemoryCacheManager<object>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by creating a CacheTracker class (as singleton) that keep tracking of cache classes when they are instanciated. Here is the code, maybe it can help.

CacheTracker.cs

```
public class CacheTracker : ICacheTracker
{
    private readonly IList<ICacheManager> _cacheList;

    public CacheTracker()
    {
        this._cacheList = new List<ICacheManager>();
    }

    public void AddCache(ICacheManager cache)
    {
        this._cacheList.Add(cache);
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<ICacheManager> GetCaches(Type cacheType)
    {
        var caches =
                        from cache in _cacheList
                        where
                            cache.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == cacheType) &&
                            cache.GetType().IsClass
                        select cache;

        return caches
            .ToList()
            .AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

ICacheTracker.cs

```
public interface ICacheTracker
{
    IReadOnlyList<ICacheManager> GetCaches(Type cacheType);
    void AddCache(ICacheManager cache);
}
```

In every cache implementation

```
public MemoryCacheManager(...
        ICacheTracker cacheTracker)
{
    ...

    cacheTracker.AddCache(this);
}
```

When I need to use all caches

```
foreach (ICacheManager item in _cacheTracker.GetCaches(typeof(IMemoryCacheManager<>)))
    item.Clear();
```